# Nginx hitting worker_connection limit

Tags: ubuntu, nginx

I'm managing an Nginx server that keeps occasionally dropping a bunch of connections, after inspecting the logs I can see that the `worker_connections` limit is being hit e.g.

```
2019/12/06 08:37:09 [alert] 14517#14517: 25000 worker_connections are not enough
```

I can see from my metrics that Nginx starts dropping connections after hitting 20k active connections despite there being 32 (auto) workers, each which should be capable of handling 25000 connections  (if my understanding is correct).

Things I've tried:

- Increasing the worker_connection limit
- Turned `multi_accept` on
- Enabled epoll - I could see that the majority of the load was handled by 2-3 worker processes and others were practically unused, although this didn't seem to really help the situation as the PID shown in the error log is almost always the same process.

I'm really stumped with what else to try, if anyone has any suggestions on what might be causing it it would be greatly appreciated.

Other relevant information:

- 32 CPUs, 64GB Memory
- Ubuntu v18.04.3
- The connections are being proxied upstream
- Nginx is averaging about 400 RPS

The full config can be found here: 
https://gist.github.com/mrcnkoba/0c4447c70e313a2ed1d7e94e1dad48a7

**UPDATE:** We started using `reuseport` which seems to have stopped the issue of connections being dropped as the load appears to be *much* more evenly spread across worker processes rather than a single worker process handling the vast majority of the load. It seems like the wrong solution for the problem, as it feels like nginx should be able to handle more connections on this given the server specs, so if anyone still has any suggestions it'd be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Can you post your nginx config, there might be a reason why all those connections are being used

Comment: worker_rlimit_nofile ?

Comment: The full nginx config can be found [here](https://pastebin.com/21gDD27u), and the `worker_rlimit_nofile` limit is 50000

Comment: it's not full, because it's only a part that includes others and they aren't shown. Often troubles of such kind arise due a self-reference (loop) in config that might be developing under a triggering condition.

Comment: Could you please add a link to the output of `sudo ss -tanp | grep nginx` ?

Comment: I ran the command but it resulted in over 1k lines of output that also included data that can’t easily be anonymised. @poige I added the full config.

Comment: I don't think so. For e. g., `pass-to-apache.partial-conf` isn't shown ) But anyways `pass-to-wordpress.partial-conf` with `proxy_pass  http://PRIVATE_IP:80` looks suspicious. Check it all twice for short-cut looping…

Comment: @poige I noticed that it was missing and simplified the configuration, please see the updates version.

Comment: Do you monitor your servers performance with something? Don't you see anything suspicious at the time when the drops are happening? In network, memory, cpu utilization should be No.1  to look for.

Comment: Yes we do, it maxes out at about 12% CPU usage although typically 5% or less. RAM usage is is no more than 5%.